# Why mysql hex result is different with shell and java

Tags: mysql, unicode, hex

I want to get the unicode representations of chinese character, e.g. `'京' --> 4eac`

`Shell`

```
➜  ~ printf "%x\n" \'京
4eac
```

`Java`

```
jshell> Integer.toHexString('京');
$14 ==> "4eac"
```

Why in mysql it has the diff result?

```
select hex('京');
+------------+
| hex('京')  |
+------------+
| E4BAAC     |
+------------+

show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                               |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                 |
```

In mysql it has to use below manner to get the same result as above

```
select hex(convert('京' using ucs2));
+--------------------------------+
| hex(convert('京' using ucs2))  |
+--------------------------------+
| 4EAC                           |
+--------------------------------+
```

So why `hex` in mysql is different with other?

In addition from unicode to character

Shell

```
➜  ~ echo '\u4eac'
京
```

Java

```
jshell> String s = "\u4eac";
s ==> "京"
```

Mysql

```
select char(0x4eac using ucs2);
+-------------------------+
| char(0x4eac using ucs2) |
+-------------------------+
| 京                      |
+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 (MySQL's utf8 or utf8mb4) is a different *encoding* than UCS2 (MySQL: ucs2).

```
'京' =
Unicode "codepoint" (in hex) '4eac' =
UCS2 encoding (2 bytes, in hex) '4EAC' =
UTF-8 encoding (3 bytes, in hex) 'E4BAAC' =
html entity '&#x4EAC;' (hex) or '&#20140;' (decimal)
```

Reference:  http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B4eac

Comment: Thanks! So in shell and jshell environment it actually used `ucs2` encoding not utf8, am I right?